# Calling a function in an async way in node

Tags: node.js, promise

a complete nodejs beginner here and learning async programming - promises in particular. But I am totally confused on how do I "convert" a sync operation like a for-loop to an async call.

```
var loopfunction = function(version:string) : void {
    console.log("Begin" + version + " Loop")
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log(version + "Number looping through is " + i)
    }
    console.log("End Loop")
}

console.log("Calling sync function")
loopfunction("First : ");
loopfunction("Second : ");
loopfunction("Third : ");
console.log("ending sync function")
```

In the above code, the 'loopfunction' calls are executed in sync. The "First" call is executed, then second and then third.

How can I write an async function/code to do the same loopfunction calls but in an async way? ie. The second and third loopfunction calls do not wait for the previous loopfunction calls to finish and run concurrently.

Thanks a lot

Comment: try this https://caolan.github.io/async/

Comment: What is your actual goal here?  You cannot actually make a synchronous set of code run asynchronously.  Async code in node.js uses native code to accomplish actually doing things in the background and then uses a callback notification to tell you when its done.  You can change the timing of your synchronous code (running on the next tick or after some timer fires), but it won't ever actually run asynchronously.  Whenever it runs, it will still be synchronous.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that answers my question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a pure async call then it could look like:

```
var loopfunction = function(version:string) : void {
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("Begin" + version + " Loop")
      for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log(version + "Number looping through is " + i)
      }
      console.log("End Loop")
    }, 0);
}

console.log("Calling sync function")
loopfunction("First : ");
loopfunction("Second : ");
loopfunction("Third : ");
console.log("ending sync function")
```

If you are thinking about creating and returning a promise:

```
var loopfunction = function(version:string) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      console.log("Begin" + version + " Loop")
      for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log(version + "Number looping through is " + i)
      }
      console.log("End Loop")
      resolve();
    });
}

console.log("Calling sync function")
loopfunction("First : ");
loopfunction("Second : ");
loopfunction("Third : ");
console.log("ending sync function")
```

However in this case you are not waiting for the promises. If you want to wait (so execute promises in "sync" way) then:

```
var loopfunction = function(version:string) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      console.log("Begin" + version + " Loop")
      for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log(version + "Number looping through is " + i)
      }
      console.log("End Loop")
      resolve();
    });
}

console.log("Calling sync function")
loopfunction("First : ").then(function(){
   return loopfunction("Second : ");
}). then(function(){
   return loopfunction("Third : ");
}). then(function(){
   console.log("ending sync function")
});
```

---

## UPDATE

If you want to see different order of results then you might try this:

```
var loopfunction = function(version:string) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      //wait for some random time before executing the code
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Begin" + version + " Loop")
        for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
          console.log(version + "Number looping through is " + i)
        }
        console.log("End Loop")
        resolve();
      }, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried running the second code block "creating and returning promises" as that is what I am trying to learn. However, still the output is - First loop starts & ends, then Second loop starts & ends and then the third. What I am looking for is like a rapid fire, kickstart the first loopfunction, let it run and while it is running, start the second and third loopfunction. The output I am trying to get is where the console.log outputs from the three different loopfunctions are not in sequence and jumbled - kind of running multiple concurrent threads if that makes sense

Comment: @Sibi I updated my answer with the code that should do what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want your long running code to not block just change it to

```
var loopfunction = function(version:string) : void {
    console.log("Begin" + version + " Loop")
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        setImmediate(function() {
            console.log(version + "Number looping through is " + i)
        })
    }
    console.log("End Loop")
}
```

If you want it also to return a result or know when it has finished, wrap the code within promises:

```
var loopfunction = function(version:string) : void {
    console.log("Begin" + version + " Loop")
    var iterations = []
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        iterations.push(new Promise(function(resolve) {
            setImmediate(function() {
                console.log(version + "Number looping through is " + i)
                resolve()
            })
        }))
    }
    return Promise.all(iterations).then(function() {
        console.log("End Loop")
    })
}
```